# Is there a term specifically applying to a three-word portmanteau?

Tags: single-word-requests, portmanteau-words, general-vs-specific

Oxford Dictionaries define a *portmanteau* as

> A word blending the sounds and combining the meanings of **two** others, for example *motel* or *brunch*.

I've also heard the term apply to three- and four-word combinations, but I'm not sure if it's correct. For my blog, I wanted to describe the Latin word *obstaculum*, which is a combination of three Latin terms, and while I could use *combination* or *portmanteau* without anyone noticing, I began wondering if there are any terms that **specifically** describe three- or four- word mergers (in that the word is exclusive to the number). I also wanted to know if a portmanteau can correctly be applied if used for more than two words.

Any help?

Comment: Wikipedia describes the word *Satanarchaeolidealcohellish* (from a children's book by Michael Ende) as a portmanteau of the words *Satan, anarchy, archaeology, lie, ideal, alcohol* and *hellish.* So presumably there's no better word for three-, four- or seven-word mergers in English.

Comment: The book was translated from the German, where the *Kofferwort* was *satanarchäolügenialkohöllisch*.

Comment: [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/portmanteau) gives **portmanteau** ... N ... 2. Also called portmanteau word. Linguistics. blend (def 10). and [**blend**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/blend) ... N ...

10.
Linguistics. a word made by putting together parts of other words ...

Comment: Yeah, the correct term is *threewordportmanteau*.

Comment: If you need a name for a three-word merger, how about *tripodmanteau*?

Comment: Isn't *obstaculum*  a core verb, modified by a prefix and turned into a noun by the addition of a suffix rather than a word made up of three **individual words**? Do 'ob-' and '-culum' really count as words? I appreciate you might still want to describe the fact that 'obstaculum' has three parts, but can't you just say it 'has three parts' or hass a 'three-part construction'?

Comment: @PeterShor - No, that's two sesquipedalian words.

Comment: A portmanteau that refers to three words is called: ***portmanteau***: *In linguistics, a portmanteau is defined as **a single morph that represents two or more morphemes***. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portmanteau

Comment: related: **1.** [What do you call the process of combining two words to create a new one?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/91306/what-do-you-call-the-process-of-combining-two-words-to-create-a-new-one) **2.** [Are there rules for constructing portmanteaux?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/75326/are-there-rules-for-constructing-portmanteaux) **3.** [What to call expressions like “Google-Fu”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/337378/what-to-call-expressions-like-google-fu)

Comment: _Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary_ (2003) confirms the definition  that Josh cites: "**portmanteau** _n_ (1579) ... **2 :** a word or morpheme whose form and meaning are derived from a blending of two or more distinct words (as _smog_ from _smoke_ and _fog_)." The correct term is indeed _portmanteau_. An example of a portmanteau word drawn from three base words is [_Komsomol_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Komsomol), the Soviet youth organization, whose source words (in Russian) are _Kommunistichesky_ (_communist_), _Soyuz_ (_alliance_), and _Molodyozhi_ (_young people_).

Comment: Similarly, if you cross-bred a half-Labrador-retriever/half-poodle with a half-chow/half-chihuahua, you would presumably get a litter of _Labradoodlechowahuas_. It's still a portmanteau, albeit it an overstuffed one.

Comment: For an interesting though rather fragmentary discussion of whether the word _Delmarva_ (from _Delaware-Maryland-Virginia_) in the place name _Delmarva Peninsula_ is a blend, a portmanteau, a syllabic abbreviation, a clipping compound, or an acronym, see [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk%3ADelmarva_Peninsula).

Comment: managed 'polymanteau'

Answer (score 1):

I can't seem to find a word for a three-part portmanteau; I kind of doubt it exists. But I think you could use a phrase like ***tripartite portmanteau***, which I think would make sense to most people. Or slap a prefix on, such as ***tri-portmanteau***, but I think that could be confusing.

And all this makes me think, maybe the best phrase is simply ***three-part portmanteau***.

Comment: That's the best I can do, I suppose... not exactly what I wanted, but I don't want to waste the bounty

Comment: yeah, not exactly a satisfying answer. but even if the word existed, nobody has ever heard of it, and you'd end up having to explain it anyway.

Comment: excellent point; that deserves the bounty in itself!

Answer (score 1):

The word you're looking for is *portmantrio*. (portmanteau + trio)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hey @Community bot: the answer was itself a portmanteau. Friedrich: I pronounce the last syllable of portmanteau “tu” so how about “portmanthree”?

Answer (score 0):

Wikipedia defines a [portmanteau](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portmanteau) as:

> a single morph that represents two or more morphemes

So perhaps the word you are looking for is portmanteau.

Assuming this is not the answer you want, we need to look further afield, and perhaps invent a new word to cover this gap in the English language.

Here is my proposal:

We can see from the Wikipedia article that portmanteaux are popular in lots of languages. The one that caught my eye was Indonesia, and the mega city:

> [Jabodetabek](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jabodetabek)

This mega city is defined as Jakarta and its suburbs, namely:

- **Ja**karta
- **Bo**gor
- **De**pok
- **Ta**ngerang
- **Bek**asi

So I looked up the meaning of [mega](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mega-):

> (originally) Very large, great. Denoting a size larger than usual.

amongst others.

It is derived from the Ancient Greek 'μέγας' (mégas, “great, large, mighty”), and as such I feel it would make an excellent prefix.

I originally came up with megaportmanteau, but I think:

> **megamanteau**

is the word we are looking for.

Comment: Except that word is a novel coining and no one will know what it means until you define it for them, every time you use it. It's a little misleading to say "X is the word we're looking for", implying we *found* it, when we actually invented it on the spot to meet the specific purpose.

Comment: While I kind of agree with Dan Bron's comment, personally, I think the word sounds good to use as is :D.

Comment: just because we're talking about made-up words doesn't mean we should make up words to define made-up words.